# Ошибка "ошибка при отрисовке кадра." компиляция проходит, симуляция не запускается

Tags: anylogic

Модель движения пешеходов, уже третья. Впервые такая ошибка. Подскажите, что это за ошибка? как исправить? В интернете есть вопросы по ней, но без ответов ([image: ошибка про запуске симуляции модели пешеходных маршрутов]